# Can not find where maven local repository path in netbeans 8.0.2 is set

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

In netbeans when I go to Tools->Options->Java->Maven panel is showing 
Maven Home: Bundeled
[Maven Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yQIQ.png)

But I can not find in Netbeans 8.0.2 that where is the maven local repository path is as it can be seen in Netbeans 7.0.1

[Maven local repository in 7.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amxXF.png)

In my system .m2 folder is located at `C:\Users\acs\.m2`

But there is another repository at `C:\Users\acs\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\maven`

Now I have installed apache-maven(which have not installed previously on sysetm) and set the MAVEN HOME path to C:\Users\acs\apache-maven-3.3.9 in netbeans

And then wanted to know that currently at what location netbeans  Maven local repository path is. But I am unable to find it in 8.0.2

Does anyone know how to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using external Maven installations, the local repository is (by default) in

```
${user.home}/.m2/repository
```

Check out [Maven Settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) or [Maven Mini Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html)

You can set another local repository dir path, changing

**Global settings**

```
${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
```

or

**User settings**

```
${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml



<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>/any_other_dir/repository</localRepository>
  
  ...
</settings>
```

If you do so, any project that use this Maven and this global/user settings, will use this repository as local repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my actual question is related to netbeans. Is netbeans where should I find the set mave repository path.

Comment: No its not. Netbeans is not configuring Maven settings. It only does references to them. You got a inner repository `C:\Users\acs\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\maven` because it was an embbeded one. In your last case, Netbeans can be delegating Maven configuration to Maven settings not to the NetBeans plugin

Comment: It means editing settings.xml will make the job done. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah! you can set anything related to maven through these settings.xml. Hope it will help :-)

Comment: Just I want to add that maven can be installed with netbeans, in this case the setting file on maven is located in this path "...\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\conf".

Answer (score 5):

Found the way.

In Project Explorer window within Netbeans you will find services tab.

> Goto:  `services->maven repositories->local->right click->properties`

You will get the Local Repository path which netbeans is using.

Comment: When I right click that, it shows blank (no location).  I'm still researching to find a solution for this.